# Execute 'adb' from an APK

Tags: android

Planning to execute `adb` to do some operation from a `TestActivity.Java` and try to execute the `TestActivity.apk`.

```
File wd = new File("/Android/android-sdk-windows/tools/");
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                      "adb shell monkey -p com.sample.cts -v 50", null, wd);
proc.waitFor();
```

Getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [adb, shell, monkey, -p, com.sample.cts, -v, 5000] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: are you trying to execute that on the phone (or emulator)? that won't work since adb is part of the sdk-tools - it's on the PC where your emulator is running (or where the phone is connected to), not in the environment within the emulator/phone

Answer (score 1):

adb stands for [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) and it's a local helper program for developers. I doubt that this program is actually located on the device itself.

Comment: Actually adb is also available on any android device, although it's an adb daemon that receives commands via usb from host's adb and it's not available to applications. API Level 12 introduces android.hardware.usb namespace, which allows some interoperation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that android sdk is not properly attach to your eclipse 
Go to preference -> click on android -> see whether all sdk are files displaying -> if it not display go for solution that i given below

This thing properly happen when antiviruses remove some sdk files in your sdk folder

**Solution:**
Once again download the sdk file from beginning or otherwise get the sdk package from others and put it